# Apple Maps searchAutoComplete structuredAddress always null

Tags: geocoding, apple-maps

Regardless of how much information is provided to the Apple Maps `searchAutoComplete` API, the response field `structuredAddress` is always null. This means I have to call the `completionUrl` in order to get a structured address of the result. This consumes quota and is an additional hop to Apple.

Example request, autocompleting "450 Post St, San Francisco":

```
https://maps-api.apple.com/v1/searchAutocomplete?
q=450%20Post%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco
&resultTypeFilter=Address
&limitToCountries=US
&lang=en-US
```

responds 2 results with the actual address found, but each having only these fields:

```
- completionUrl
- displayLines
- location
```

Anyone figured this out?